# How to get new message received from the telegram channel using telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I used the code given [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html) to receive new message from the user but it does not work when a new message arrives in the telegram channel.

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.stringify())
```

Setting `events.NewMessage(chat='chat')` or `events.NewMessage(chat='channel')` didn't work.

How can a telegram bot get new message event from a telegram channel ?

Comment: `chats` is used to filter by a very specific chat given some identifier like ID or username, not type.

Comment: If not using chat filter , then How to get the new message from the channel ?

Comment: As far as I remember, bots will not receive the channel messages. This is by Telegram’s design. You need to create a user session for this.

Comment: I have seen many telegram channels in which bot replies whenever `/ somecommand`  is issued.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a bot to receive all messages, you first need to configure it in [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather) by disabling the bot privacy:

1. /start
2. /mybots
3. (select a bot)
4. Bot Settings
5. Group Privacy
6. Turn off

With that done, add the bot as admin to your broadcast channel (they can't be normal members here). Your code should look like this:

```py
CHANNEL = ...  # id, username or invite link of the channel

# the first parameter is the `chats=`, you can use a named argument if you want
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(CHANNEL))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.stringify())
```

If you want to handle messages from **all** broadcast channels your group is in, use a more advanced filter:

```py
# megagroups (supergroups) are channels too, so we need `not e.is_group`
# this lambda takes the event, which has these boolean properties
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: e.is_channel and not e.is_group))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.stringify())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get the message text instead of the entire json, you can try this

```
print(event.message.message)
```